# CompassLayer not showing up in WorldWind

Tags: java, worldwind

I have a `WorldWindow` with various `RenderableLayer`s on it.  I'd like to add a `CompassLayer` at run-time.

```
try {

    String compassPath = "images" + File.separator + "CompassRoseWhite.png";
    String compassImg  = new ClassPathResource(compassPath).getURL().toString();
    compass            = new CompassLayer(compassImg);
    worldWindow.getModel().getLayers().add(compass);

} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Unfortunately, I do not see the compass anywhere on-screen.  I have tried:

- manually setting the compass position using `compass.setLocationCenter(...)`
- adding another type of layer (an `IconLayer` with a `UserFacingIcon`), and this worked fine, indicating it's not an intrinsic issue with how I am adding layers or anything like that.
- logging the current layers to make sure it was added, using:

  `logger.debug("Cur layers = " + worldWindow.getModel().getLayers().toString());`

I got back:

> Cur layers = Stars, Atmosphere, Bing Imagery VASCustom, Scale bar, Compass, View Controls, Renderable, Renderable, Renderable, Renderable, Compass,

How can I effectively debug my invisible compass problem?  Thank you!

### Update

I've simplified my code to use the *existing* `compassLayer`, and I've determined the problem is my use of `setLocationCenter`, i.e.,

```
compass = (CompassLayer) worldWindow.getModel().getLayers().getLayerByName("Compass");

// this works ...           
// compass.setPosition(AVKey.SOUTHEAST);
// compass.setLocationOffset(new Vec4(0, 20));

// this does not work ...  
compass.setLocationCenter(worldWindow.getView().getCenterPoint());

// this part works fine
String compassPath = "images" + File.separator + "CompassRoseWhite.png";
String compassImg  = new ClassPathResource(compassPath).getURL().toString();
compass.setIconFilePath(compassImg);
compass.setEnabled(true);
```

So what I need to determine is what exactly is wrong with the `setLocationCenter` logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two primary problems with my code.

1. I already had a `compassLayer` and should have used it instead of making a new one, ie,

   `compass = (CompassLayer) worldWindow.getModel().getLayers().getLayerByName("Compass");`
2. When you use `computePointFromPosition()` you get back absolute Cartesian coordinates.  Then you need to convert these to pixel coordinates using `View.project()`.  Finally you need to offset by the current `View`.  Ie,

```
Vec4 vecOwnship = worldWindow.getModel()
                             .getGlobe()
                             .computePointFromPosition(ownshipPosition);
Vec4 vecScreen  = worldWindow.getView().project(vecOwnship);
Rectangle viewPort = worldWindow.getView().getViewport();
compass.setLocationCenter(new Vec4(viewPort.x + vecScreen.x, viewPort.y + vecScreen.y, 0));
```

Fixing these issues solved the problem and now the compass shows up.

Comment: Partial credit to [this source](https://forum.worldwindcentral.com/forum/world-wind-java-forums/development-help/16132-trying-to-get-real-screen-coordinates-of-a-position) for my solution.